# More efficient way to filter products

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, performance

I have an array of products that are input into a state called "products" that are the filtered versions of "baseProducts" formatted like this

```
{
    "data": {
        "field_product_series": "sc950",
        "field_product_roll_size": "15-x-10-yds",
        "field_product_width": null,
        "field_product_width_in": "15",
        "field_product_length": null,
        "field_product_length_in_yards": "10",
        "field_product_finish": "gloss",
        "field_product_color": "bright-gold-metallic",
        "field_product_color_number": "213",
        "field_product_durability": "10-years",
        "field_product_vinyl_class": "g31a",
        "sku": "ASC950-213-1510P",
        "title": "15'' x 10 yards Avery SC950 Gloss Bright Gold 10 year Long Term Punched 2.0 Mil Metallic Cast Cut Vinyl (Color Code 213)"
    }
}
```

I am trying to be able to filter products based off of a list of fields. I am currently filtering the products like this

```
const filteredProducts = baseProducts.filter(product => 
                (filters.includes(product.data.field_product_roll_size)) 
            || (filters.includes(product.data.field_product_width_in)) 
            || (filters.includes(product.data.field_product_length_in_yards)) 
            || (filters.includes(product.data.field_product_series))
            || (filters.includes(product.data.field_product_color))
            || (filters.includes(product.data.field_product_color_number))
            || (filters.includes(product.data.field_product_finish)));
        setProducts(filteredProducts);
```

For example selecting 'roll size' adds that size to the filters state and baseProducts is being filtered by the updated filters state. I know this is inefficient and it really turns into a headache if I try to be able to select multiple filters which I am trying like so

```
if (filters.length == 2) {
            const filteredProducts = baseProducts.filter(product => 
                (filters.includes(product.data.field_product_roll_size) && filters.includes(product.data.field_product_width_in))
            || (filters.includes(product.data.field_product_roll_size) && filters.includes(product.data.field_product_color))
            || (filters.includes(product.data.field_product_roll_size) && filters.includes(product.data.field_product_length_in_yards))
            || (filters.includes(product.data.field_product_roll_size) && filters.includes(product.data.field_product_series))
            || (filters.includes(product.data.field_product_roll_size) && filters.includes(product.data.field_product_color_number))
setProducts(filteredProducts);
```

I have over 10k products and want to be able to use at least 8 filters, it is getting more complicated and I am struggling to find a better way to filter, any help is appreciated

I have a demo set up here http://gatsby.htm-mbs.com:8000/cast-vinyl

and the full repo is here https://github.com/nicholastorr/gatsby-d7/blob/master/src/components/Sidebar.js but it is very messy, trying to focus on optimizing filters first

Comment: If you have 10k products, that filtering should definitely not be done in a React app.

Comment: @EmileBergeron what do you mean? It is able to load and filter the products just fine I just need a more efficient way

Comment: This kind of filtering is usually done on the backend because it is so much more efficient than to load everything on the frontend and perform filtering there. Since you most probably don't display everything at once, you must have some kind of pagination, so you would only need to load a certain amount of data at once. Anyway, if you insist on doing it this way, could you provide an example of what `filters` may contain?

Comment: I second @EmileBergeron's note about pagination & filtering not being done on FE. Now, let us say, I have the below in filters array: `filters = ["15-x-10-yds", "10-years", "15", "12", "217"];` - would you please confirm if the `"15"` needs to checked for `"field_product_width_in"`, or `"field_product_length_in_yards"`, or any prop is fine (doesn't really matter which prop has the value `"15"`)?

Comment: Assuming, it doesn't matter which prop has the value `"15"` (from previous comment), please try this: `const filteredProducts = baseProducts.filter(product => Object.values(product.data).some(v => filters.includes(v)));`